# Experienced system builder is stumped

Tags: windows-7

I've always been building my own PC's for a while, but I'm starting to get quite stressed and hung up over an issue I'm having with my new build. I cannot get past the initial startup during Windows 7 installation. Just as the "Starting Windows" animation gets going, it stops. The system stops responding. I tried on a USB stick as well as a DVD. Same problem.

My build is as follows:

- Asus P8Z68m-Pro
- Coolermaster G550M (pulled from my previous working system)
  3570k
- Palit GeForce 460 GTX
- 4GB Corsair DDR3 1600MHz
- Samsung EVO 850 250GB SSD
- Windows 7 Pro

I ran memtest86 on the system and there were no errors.
I'm able to use disk OSs just fine.
I tried turning off AHCI in the BIOS and rebooted.

So I really don't know what else I can do. If this is a hardware issue, how an earth would I even begin to diagnose it? Bad PSU? Well, Prime95 worked fine on Hirens Boot CD, as did all the other diagnostic utilities. There's a complete lack of any sort of error message when I try for the installation. The system just stops in its tracks. Bad motherboard? Bad CPU? Bad RAM? Bad PSU? I have literally NO idea.

CPU temperatures are OK. I can play around in BIOS all day with no issues. I have cross-checked the settings many times. See, I really enjoy playing at tweaking PCs, but when these zero-sum errors with no apparent causes run the show, I feel that this isn't the hobby for me.

I'm at a loss here guys. I've been to my wits ends and back again. It's pathetic that it's all this over a freaking PC.

Comment: Will safe mode load?

Comment: Try the F8 options on the boot screen (safe mode, command line, boot logging - not sure which are offered by Win7). If this doesn't do anything, try the SSD in another machine: if it doesn't boot, then install W7 in that machine and bring it back; if it does boot, install boot logging software.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have ahci enabled in the bios, but you are not installing the driver when you set up Windows 7. 
Try turning off AHCI in the BIOS and reboot. Then you can go from there.

Comment: Tried this.. Sorry I forgot to mention that I had.